# can't save on database because : Access denied for user 'id6266174_alfa'@'%' to database 'myproject'. using php 5.5.1.1

Tags: php, mysql, database, php-5.5

I'm very new to PHP so please bear with me. I have a registration form and I'm submitting the values entered on that form and having them inserted into a MySQL Database table, but I'm getting the following denied:

Access denied for user 'id6266174_alfa'@'%' to database 'myproject'

I've granted all the access that is possible to the user that I'm using in my code, but I'm still having this error. Any help is appreciated and points will be awarded.
 **FYI**: I'm using an *old* version of PHP <5.5.1.1>.
and i have tried running this program on my localhost, the data can be saved on my database. but why? if i upload/hosting i have an error

and this is my code

```
<?php

include 'koneksi.php';

$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$address = $_POST["address"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$pin = $_POST["pin"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pwd = $_POST["pwd"];

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","id6266174_alfa","12345") or die ("koneksi gagal");
mysql_select_db("id6266174_myproject",$conn);

$sqlstr="insert into users (id,fname,lname,address,city,pin,email,password) values ('', '$fname', '$lname', '$address', '$city', '$pin', '$email', '$pwd')";
    $hasil = mysql_query($sqlstr,$conn);
header ("location:login.php");
 ?>
```

Comment: Did u check that the database is on the same machine as the PHP server?

Comment: Also check, whether the user 'id6266174_alfa' as write access to the 'id6266174_myproject' DB